# ASP.NET Core + Webpack(HMR) doesn't see file

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, webpack

I am configuring webpack HMR for an ASP.NET project.

Here is my `webpack.config.js` file code with all paths:

```
  const path = require('path');
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const devMode = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';
let dist = 'wwwroot'

module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  entry: {
    app: './src/js/app.js'
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, dist),
    filename: 'js/[name].min.js',
    publicPath: dist +'/'
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.js']
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
        {
          test: /\.js$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          use: {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            options: {
              cacheDirectory: true
            }
          }
        },
        {
          test: /\.ts$/,
          use: [
              {
                loader: 'awesome-typescript-loader',
                options: { configFileName: path.resolve(__dirname, 'tsconfig.json') }
              },
          ]
        },
        {
          test: /\.s?[ac]ss$/,
          use: ['style-loader', MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader',
              {
                loader: "sass-loader",
                options: {
                  includePaths: ["./src/sass"]
                }
              }
          ]
        },
        {
          test: /\.(png|jp(e*)g|gif|svg)$/,
          use: [
              {
                loader: 'file-loader',
                options: {
                  name: "[name].[ext]",
                  outputPath: 'img/',
                  publicPath: '../images/',
                }
              }
          ]
        },
        {
          test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|otf)$/,
          use: [
              {
                loader: 'file-loader',
                options: {
                  name: "[name].[ext]",
                  outputPath: 'fonts/',
                  publicPath: '../fonts/',
                }
              }

          ]
        },
        {
          test: /\.svg$/,
          loader: 'svg-inline-loader',
          options: {
            name: "[name].[ext]",
            outputPath: 'img/',
            publicPath: '../images/',
          }
        }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      "jquery.validation": "jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.js"
    }
  },
  plugins: [
      new CleanWebpackPlugin(dist, {}),
      new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
        filename: "css/[name].min.css",
        chunkFilename: "[id].css",
      }),
      new CopyWebpackPlugin([
          {
            from: './src/img',
            to: 'images',
            toType: 'dir'
          }
      ]),
  ],
}
```

I added HMR via `npm install aspnet-webpack webpack-hot-middleware webpack-dev-middleware -D`

And added code to Startup.cs:

```
 app.UseWebpackDevMiddleware(new WebpackDevMiddlewareOptions
            {
                HotModuleReplacement = true
            });
```

And here is how I try to use a script in `_Layout.cshtml` file

`<script src="~/js/app.min.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>`

But I get this error, and I don't understand why; I have a wwwroot folder and a file in it.

[image]

I tried to rebuild and clean the project, but it does not help.

How I can solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I just update webpack config like this

```
  const path = require('path');
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
let dist = 'src'
module.exports = {
   mode: 'development',
   entry: {
    app: './wwwroot/source/app.js'
    },
   output: {
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, dist),
      filename: '[name].min.js',
      publicPath: 'src/'
   },
   module: {
    rules: [
        {
          test: /\.js$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          use: {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            options: {
              cacheDirectory: true
            }
          }
        },
        {
          test: /\.ts$/,
          use: [
              {
                loader: 'awesome-typescript-loader',
                options: { configFileName: path.resolve(__dirname, 'tsconfig.json') }
              },
          ]
        },
        {
          test: /\.s?[ac]ss$/,
          use: ['style-loader', MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader',
              {
                loader: "sass-loader",
                options: {
                  includePaths: ["./wwwroot/sass"]
                }
              }
          ]
        },
        {
          test: /\.(png|jp(e*)g|gif|svg)$/,
          use: [
              {
                loader: 'file-loader',
                options: {
                  name: "[name].[ext]",
                  outputPath: 'img/',
                  publicPath: '../images/',
                }
              }
          ]
        },
        {
          test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|otf)$/,
          use: [
              {
                loader: 'file-loader',
                options: {
                  name: "[name].[ext]",
                  outputPath: 'fonts/',
                  publicPath: '../fonts/',
                }
              }

          ]
        },
        {
          test: /\.svg$/,
          loader: 'svg-inline-loader',
          options: {
            name: "[name].[ext]",
            outputPath: 'img/',
            publicPath: '../images/',
          }
        }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      "jquery.validation": "jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.js"
    }
  },
  plugins: [
      new CleanWebpackPlugin(dist, {}),
      new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
        filename: "css/[name].min.css",
        chunkFilename: "[id].css",
      }),
      new CopyWebpackPlugin([
          {
            from: './wwwroot/img',
            to: 'images',
            toType: 'dir'
          }
      ]),
  ],
};
```

And all okay now.